# Jenkins Update Issues

Tags: windows, jenkins

So, I think I might broken our Jenkins Windows Server or instance.

I ran a update, to the latest version as it was due and after the update all the repo's, jobs and configurations are missing. On a side note, all the config. etc are still in the windows jeknins folder.

Happened to anybody before and what can I do to fix this.

Any help would be awesome.

Thanks.

Comment: You say "Windows Server instance" but you tagged "linux", so which is it?

Comment: Yes, I meant Windows, not Linux. Jenkins is running on a Windows System.